# Render a child component only after async method is completed in parent's mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, async-await, vue-component, vuex

I have a parent component which renders a child component.  I am making an async call (an axios 'get' request from Vuex actions) from inside the `mounted` of the parent component, which fetches the data required for the child component.

I want to prevent the rendering of the child component til that async call is completed.  Can someone suggest some elegant approach?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## v-if

```html
<child v-if="mydata" />
```

`mydata` can be a data property initialized to `null`:

```js
data() {
  return {
    mydata: null
  }
}
```

When that's populated in `created`/`mounted`, the `child` component will show.

```js
async created() {
  const response = await axios // ...
  this.mydata = response.data;
}
```

---

**EDIT:**  Based on your comments below.  For Vuex, do this instead:

- Continue using the `v-if`
- Use a computed instead of a data property:

```js
computed: {
   mydata() {
     return this.$store.state.mydata;
   }
}
```

alternate syntax using `mapState`

```js
import { mapState } from 'vuex';

computed: {
   ...mapState(['mydata'])
}
```